# binlog_format = STATEMENT and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

can a MySQL slave instance have different row values for the same ID when binlog_format is set to STATEMENT and we insert something like:

```
insert into foo values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

As I understand it, the slave read the SQL statement and execute it thus, if the replication is lagging, could lead to differences for the same row. Right or wrong ?

How can I avoid this situation ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly safe in statement level replication. The TIMESTAMP is written to the binary log, so the value for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will be consistent across the master and the slave even if the slave is behind. You can also use the `NOW()` function safely for the same reason.

The function to avoid is `SYSDATE()`, which will not use the TIMESTAMP from the binary log, and therefore the slave's value will represent when the statement ran on the slave, rather than when the statement ran on the master.

Comment: Ok. Got it. All non-deterministic functions (whatever we name a function) is bad when using STATEMENT based replication. If I read it right, we should go for either MIXED or full ROW replication. The former has my preference though since it can combine pros of both worlds. Thank you !

Comment: There are ways to make non-deterministic functions work with statement-level replication in some cases. I use MySQL 5.0, so statement-level replication is my only option. If I want to insert a value from a non-deterministic function, I just assign it to a local variable first, and it is replicated properly. For example, instead of `insert into test.uuids values(uuid());` I do `set @uuid = uuid(); insert into test.uuids values(@uuid);` to get the same value on the master and slave DB.